# Share apk via bluetooth

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, bluetooth, nexus-5, apk

I have to receive an apk by bluetooth to my phone, but i can't do it, because in my phone(nexus 5 running android 6.0.1) blocks the file, the devices are paired, I tried with others files like images, and i can receive them, but not apk files, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to either compress the .apk (using a app like RAR) and then try to send the compressed file, or you can try to sent the file using another software like "Bluetooth File Transfer".